# PHP Liveserver, Visual Code, SASS can't work together

Tags: php, css

I'm quite new to coding in Visual Code, and been able to use LiveServer flawlessly with html.

But I decided to go with php for a project, so I made a server with XAMPP, downloaded chrome extension for Liveserver, but it doesn't work as it should:

If I add something (like a div) in e.g. index.php, Ctrl+S, the browser reloads, and shows the new div flawlessly.

On the other hand, if I change some styling, which I do through SASS (yes, "watching" is on"), LiveServer detects some change, reloads the page, but uses the same css as before. Checked with browser F12, it is DIFFERENT from the one saved in the original folder...

So basically no matter how I change css, browser doesn't reload the new one.

Can you help me to make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear browser cache and check if there is some errors in the console (where you watching sass files)

Comment: Doesn't work, console shows no errors at all.

But if I make a new chrome tab, and navigate to the php, basically opening the project again in a new tab, it DOES load the newly saved css.

Comment: OK this is weird as khmm...
Somehow my media query settings gotten triggered by moving the window, everything is fine!
Thx anyway.